# Design issue in case of inheritence

Tags: inheritance

I've a design related question w.r.t inheritence.

```
Class A

protected field1
protected field2
protected field3

private List<B>
```

Class B should contain field1, field2 and field3 + certain it's own properties.

Is it OK if B can be made as subclass of A.

This relationship somehow doesn't feel ok as 
my requirement is ,
When object A has field1, field2 and field3, we should make sure that
each object in List of object A should have the same fields.

Is there any alternative to ensure this above mentioned condition.

Thanks.

Comment: Should it not be "...that each object in List of Object B should have the same fields"?

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is one option. I would use it in this case.

Another would be composition, but then you need to expose the fields somehow, which depends on the usage intended

```
Class B {

private A a

// Constructor
public B(A instanceOfA) {
   this.a = instanceOfA
}

public setField1(value) {
   this.a.field1 = value
}

...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go for composition always unless there is a strict IS-A relationship between the two classes. Design with composition is much more flexible and maintainable.

Comment: You have a valid point, though in this case I would rather use inheritance, because it makes changes more transparent. Otherwise you would have to change Class B as well if you change Class A. Furthermore it seems imperative that all the fields are the same thus I would assume that is a "IS-A" relationship